# Set up weekly reports on Google Cloud Billing

Tags: google-maps, google-cloud-platform

My company is using Google Maps for 3 projects.

I would like to generate a report every week with how much we have spent.

Below I have a filter set up for what I would like. Basically I just want the total amount for the week.

I understand there is something called "BigQuery" in Billing Exports. Before I dive into that I was wondering what is the easiest way to do this.

Bryan

[image: Filters]

Comment: standard practice is export your billing information to BiqQuery, then query BigQuery. Google has several documents detailing this, others have written many more.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to apply the SKU filter to get a breakdown of the specific Maps API.  See: https://developers.google.com/maps/billing/understanding-cost-of-use#view-cost-by-sku

Comment: I really just want the aggregate. For all Projects/SKUs how much did we spend in a week.

Comment: If I understand correctly you're happy with the report you've created in the attached image but find it inconvenient to create that view each time you visit the billing console?  If this is true I don't blame you.  Unfortunately they don't support saved views or custom reports.  See the FAQ: Can I save or bookmark my billing report view?  https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/reports#faqs

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following steps:

1. Set `Group by` field to `Project`.
2. Set `Products` field to `Maps API`.
3. Under `SKUs`, you may set additional filters if you wish to filter the usage only for the specific APIs under the Maps API
4. Then set the `Time Range` to `Custom Range` then select the preferred date range you'd like to visit.

So far, this is the way you can achieve the segregation of the reports per project. You may also select the specific projects you'd like to see under the `Projects` field.